# Database recommendation

Tags: database, sqlite

I'm writing a CAD (Computer-Aided Design) application. I'll need to ship a library of 3d objects with this product. These are simple objects made up of nothing more than 3d coordinates and there are going to be no more than about 300 of them.

I'm considering using a relational database for this purpose. But given my simple needs, I don't want any thing complicated. Till now, I'm leaning towards SQLite. It's small, runs within the client process and is claimed to be fast. Besides I'm a poor guy and it's free.

But before I commit myself to SQLite, I just wish to ask your opinion whether it is a good choice given my requirements. Also is there any equivalent alternative that I should try as well before making a decision?

**Edit**:

I failed to mention earlier that the above-said CAD objects that I'll ship are not going to be immutable. I expect the user to edit them (change dimensions, colors etc.) and save back to the library. I also expect users to add their own newly-created objects. Kindly consider this in your answers.

(Thanks for the answers so far.)

Comment: really also depends on your OS / programming language platform. What are you using? C#/.NET on Windows? Java on Linux?

Comment: Marc, I'll be using C# on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

The real thing to consider is what your program does with the data. Relational databases are designed to handle complex relationships between sets of data. However, they're not designed to perform complex calculations.

Also, the amount of data and relative simplicity of it suggests to me that you could simply use a flat file to store the coordinates and read them into memory when needed. This way you can design your data structures to more closely reflect how you're going to be using this data, rather than how you're going to store it.

Many languages provide a mechanism to write data structures to a file and read them back in again called [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization). Python's [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) is one such library, and I'm sure you can find one for whatever language you use. Basically, just design your classes or data structures as dictated by how they're used by your program and use one of these serialization libraries to populate the instances of that class or data structure.

**edit:** The requirement that the structures be mutable doesn't really affect much with regard to my answer - I still think that serialization and deserialization is the best solution to this problem. The fact that users need to be able to modify and save the structures necessitates a bit of planning to ensure that the files are updated completely and correctly, but ultimately I think you'll end up spending less time and effort with this approach than trying to marshall SQLite or another embedded database into doing this job for you.

The only case in which a database would be better is if you have a system where multiple users are interacting with and updating a central data repository, and for a case like that you'd be looking at a database server like MySQL, PostgreSQL, or SQL Server for both speed and concurrency.

You also commented that you're going to be using C# as your language. .NET has support for serialization [built in](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization#.NET_Framework) so you should be [good to go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serialization+C%23).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to consider using [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/performance.html), it's really lightweight and fast.

Answer (score 1):

When you say you'll have a library of 300 3D objects, I'll assume you mean objects for your code, not models that users will create.

I've read that [object databases](http://www.odbms.org/) are well suited to help with CAD problems, because they're perfect for chasing down long reference chains that are characteristic of complex models.  Perhaps something like [db4o](http://www.db4o.com/?src=ODBMS-sidebar) would be useful in your context.

Comment: The library I'll ship will contain sort of a default set of objects. Users will be allowed to alter them and save changes back into the library. Also they will be allowed to create new objects of their own and add to the library.

Answer (score 0):

How many objects are you shipping? Can you define each of these Objects and their coordinates in an xml file? So basically use a distinct xml file for each object? You can place these xml files in a directory. This can be a simple structure.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a SQL database. You can easy describe every 3D object with an XML file. Pack this files in a directory and pack (zip) all. If you need easy access to the meta data of the objects, you can generate an index file (only with name or description) so not all objects must be parsed and loaded to memory (nice if you have something like a library manager)

There are quick and easy SAX parsers available and you can easy write a XML writer (or found some free code you can use for this).

Many similar applications using XML today. Its easy to parse/write, human readable and needs not much space if zipped.

I have used Sqlite, its easy to use and easy to integrate with own objects. But I would prefer a SQL database like Sqlite more for applications where you need some good searching tools for a huge amount of data records.

Answer (score 0):

For the specific requirement i.e. to provide a library of objects shipped with the application a database system is probably not the right answer.

First thing that springs to mind is that you probably want the file to be updatable i.e. you need to be able to drop and updated file into the application without changing the rest of the application.

Second thing is that the data you're shipping is immutable - for this purpose therefore you don't need the capabilities of a relational db, just to be able to access a particular model with adequate efficiency.

For simplicity (sort of) an XML file would do nicely as you've got good structure. Using that as a basis you can then choose to compress it, encrypt it, embed it as a resource in an assembly (if one were playing in .NET) etc, etc.

Obviously if SQLite stores its data in a single file *per database* and if you have other reasons to need the capabilities of a db in you storage system then yes, but I'd want to think about the utility of the db to the app as a whole first.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server CE is free, has a small footprint (no service running), and is SQL Server compatible